# Can I stop someone answering my questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can I stop a specific person answering my questions?

Comment: why so many downvotes? it may not be directly helpful for you, but that doesn't mean that the question is just dumb

Comment: @SYS_V what do you mean? what is there to disagree with in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such facility in StackExchange...